# How would I translate this to RegEx?

Tags: regex, excel

I'm having trouble to translate this to RegEx:

Actual file format (For excel spreadsheet):

- [demo-_File.xls]'SheEt_nAme'!CA
- [samPle file 2.xls]'demo Sheet'!D

#### Inside the bracket and single quote:

- Accept any characters from a to z (Regardless of case)
- Accepts special characters -_. and space.

#### After the exclamation mark, it should accept up to 4 capital characters.

Comment: Could you please show your current code, the part where you are using RegExp?

Comment: /\[a-zA-Z0-9\s&-_\]'Item_Sheet'(!)[A-Z0-9]+/  and it doesn't really matches the pattern above.

Comment: What do you mean by "translate to RegEx" ? I assume you're using the `VBScript.RegExp` object to test something?

Comment: I'm using javascript. What I wanted to achieve is to parse an excel file and check if the string matches the pattern above.

Comment: @JamesM. Do you have any restrictions on characters between the single quote and the exclamation mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
\[[\w\s&.-]*\]'[\w\s&.-]+'![A-Z]{1,4}
```

In JS:

```
var re = /\[[\w\s&.-]*\]'[\w\s&.-]+'![A-Z]{1,4}/gi;
```

`[\w\s&.-]*` will match all alphanumeric characters and `_` with spaces, `&`, `.` and `-`. The `[A-Z]{1,4}` will match 1 to 4 uppercase English letters. The `i` option will make matching case-insensitive. If you want to allow digits in the last part, just revert them to `[A-Z0-9]{1,4}`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oE1yV9/3)